# Configure hostname for syslog driver in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs

Running ECS with an EC2 Container Instance

I am using the syslog driver to log to Papertrail

The papertrail logs are showing a random IP address as the host; I'd prefer that to be something meaningful. Ideally specified at the container level, but specified at the container-instance would be acceptable as well.

I have tried setting the hostname parameter of the container in my task, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

I think I can manage this by changing my driver to journal and handling it on the container instance setup, but I'd like to see if I can do it from within the ECS configuration.